# Expo - React Native - How to drag and drop image in expo web

Tags: react-native, drag-and-drop, expo

I would like to drag and drop image files to my component. Despite searching github,expo. I can't find how to do that. Any ideas?

[image: component]

Comment: I think the only way that I know how to do this would be to have a separate component for web, using normal html form attributes to make drag and drop work :(